# Creating a JSF project with Maven and IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsf, intellij-idea

I want to create a `JSF` project with `Maven` and `IntelliJ`. right now i don't know how to start. in fact, because of my project should be under `Maven`, i think i have to start a `Maven` project and then add `JSF` configuration to it but i don't know how!

is there a predefined way or after creating `Maven` project, i have to create `JSF` project structure by hand? For example i have to edit `pom.xml` by hand and then Maven adds `JSF` libraries to my project? is this the way?

i cant find out any resource on the web. there is some tutorials but all of them old and by `Eclipse` that has differences with new IntelliJ.

How i can do this?

Comment: Which is your server?

Comment: Can't you use a Java EE server like WildFly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to use Tomcat [here](http://musingsinjava.wordpress.com/2014/11/02/enabling-jsf-2-2-and-cdi-1-2-on-tomcat-8/) there is a good tutorial with recent versions. As starting point choose the `maven-archetype-webapp` Maven archetype.

If you can use WildFly you have the `wildfly-javaee7-webapp-blank-archetype` Maven archetype.